# Como colocar um alert de sucesso em uma inserção de dados via ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, banco-de-dados, jsp

estou mexendo em um projeto em andamento e o que preciso fazer nele é colocar um alert e atualizar a página após inserir dados no banco. Os dados estão sendo inseridos através de uma planilha, ou seja, cada item é uma linha da planilha que contém outras tantas colunas. Da forma que coloquei o alert ele está aparecendo o alert para cada item que for inserido com sucesso, ou seja, se a planilha tiver 50 itens irá aparecer 50 alerts de sucesso. Eu gostaria que aparecesse apenas um no final de todos serem inseridos.

Código:

```
<script>

$("#salvar").click(function(){

    var indice = ${itens_camada.size()};
    var valores = "";
    var idCamada =  ${idCamada};
    var idInstituicao =  ${idInstituicao}
    var idMunicipio =  ${idMunicipio}

    for ( var i = 0; i < indice ; i++ ) {

    $("#item_"+i).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {                                                       
        valores +=   this.value + "┆";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    });

    var dados =  "idUsuario=1"
            +"&idCamada="+idCamada
            +"&idInstituicaoFonte="+idInstituicao
            +"&dataColeta=2016-11-17"
            +"&idMunicipio="+idMunicipio
            +"&camposInseridos="+valores.substr(0, valores.length - 1);

            sendPOST(dados, i);

            valores = "";
        }                                               
});

function sendPOST(dados, i){

    $.ajax( {
        url: "${wsadpa}importar/?"+ dados,                                 
        type: 'POST',                                                                                                    
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,  

        success: function(data) {                                                                          
            Sucesso(i);
        }, 

        error: function (data, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Erro");                                        
        }       
    });                                                 
 }

 function Sucesso(i){
    $("#item_"+i).addClass("success");
    alert("Importação de Dados realizada com sucesso!"); // Aparece para cada item inserido
    location.reaload(); // Funciona OK                  
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: Tenta criar um contador para cada registro salvo, daí no Success você faz um if(contador == numeroLinhas) { alert('Salvo') }

Answer (score 0):

```
var qtdRegistros = dados.length;
var contador = 0; 
success: (function(data) { 
 contador++; 
 if (contador == dados.length) 
  alert('Mensagem');
});
```

Implementa um contador e compara se os registros inseridos são a mesma quantidade que a dos teus dados.